# Can't sent radio button value to SQL

Tags: html, css, sql, asp-classic

I'm making a page where I need to accept/decline rows from my tables by radio buttons and then send the row of data to a table in SQL.

I have been stuck on this for a few days now and I couldn't find any helpful information online so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my Html:

```
<div>
    <form id="canceltable" onsubmit="" method="post" action="admin.asp">
        <table id="CancelRequestTable">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 200px;" />
                <td style="width: 200px;" />
                <td style="width: 200px;" />
                <td style="width: 200px;" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">Cancel Request Table</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Start Date</td>
                <td>End Date</td>
                <td>Accept/Decline</td>
            </tr>
            <% Set objDBConn=S erver.CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection") objDBConn.Open "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=*****\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=*****;User ID=****;Password=****;" Set objDBCommand=S erver.CreateObject( "ADODB.Command") objDBCommand.ActiveConnection=o bjDBConn objDBCommand.CommandText="spCancelRequestTable" objDBCommand.CommandType=a dCmdStoredProc Set objDBRS=S erver.CreateObject( "ADODB.RecordSet") objDBRS.open objDBCommand,,adOpenForwardOnly Do until objDBRS.eof %>
            <tr>
                <td class="Column4Table">
                    <%response.Write(objDBRS(0))%>
                </td>
                <td class="Column4Table">
                    <%response.Write(objDBRS(1))%>
                </td>
                <td class="Column4Table">
                    <%response.Write(objDBRS(2))%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio<%=a%>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" name="radio<%=a%>" />
                </td>
            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <% 
                        a=a+1
                        objDBRS.movenext
                    Loop
                    Set objDBCommand=nothing
                    objDBConn.Close
                    Set objDBConn=nothing
                 %>
             </tr>
         </table>
         <div id="ButtonSubmit2"> <strong><i>Submit</i></strong></div>
     </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: S erver.CreateObject => does this work? Maybe add the asp tag to your question. You may provide more information - what the problem is and what you tried so far.

Comment: What does your admin.asp page look like - in particular your request.form statements and your database insert code?

Comment: @ByronMcGrath Is this question resolved?  Was it a typo like F.Müller mentioned?  This question has ended up abandoned.  Please help SO to remain tidy and work toward some sort of resolution.  If the `S erver` typo was the problem, you might consider deleting the question because it will be low value to all future SO readers.  If Nathan Rice's answer is the solution, please award it the green tick.  Otherwise, please seek additional help by clarifying your question or commenting on Nathan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing a value attribute for your radio buttons. You want something like this:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio<%=sql1%>" id="RadioGroup1_0">
  <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="radio<%=sql2%>" id="RadioGroup1_1">
</form>
```